# How to kill a process?

Tags: windows, memory, powershell, process

I am using Scilab to access a software called LTSpice (XVIIx64.exe) and whenever I use taskkill/powershell.exe "Get-Process XVIIx64 | Stop-Process". or whatever killing commands, it doesn't actually kill the process (it does close the program, but it still is there in the memory as shown in the picture below). Once I repeat the code in scilab another instance of LTSPICe (XVIIx64.exe) is created in memory and with time there are so many of them that scilab shuts down as it cannot allocate more memory :(. How can I actually kill this process? It's also strange that in the error message it is mentioned "child process of PID 18208" could not be terminated, however PID 18208 does not show up in tasklist (View the attachment).

[image: ERROR Message]

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
Get-Process -Name XVIIx64 | 
%{Stop-Process -Force}
```